# Add prev and next buttons to li item php or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ul being populated with li elements via php.

I would like to be able to add prev next buttons in the li items to access the prev and next items in the list. The list items open a jquery modal with a href of #example. How do i add the href value to the prev and next buttons in the modal with query? or do i add them with php.

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul class="gallery">
        <?php
        foreach ($employees as $employee1) {
            echo '<li>
                    <a href="#' . $employee1[0] . '"  data-toggle="modal" class="modalLink"><img src="assets/img/' . $employee1[0] . '.jpg"/></a>
                </li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="modals">

        <?php
        foreach ($employees as $employee2) {
            echo '
            <div id="' . $employee2[0] . '" class="modal hide fade container" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a href="">prev</a>
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        &times;
                    </button><a href="" class="nextarrow">next</a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ........
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
        ?>

</div>
```

Comment: tip: you can use the same variable in both of your loops, no need for `employee1` and `employee2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a common class to all "prev" links, and another class to all "next" links, also it's easier to find the next/prev modal if you get rid of the container list:

**HTML**

```
<div id="modals">
    <?php
    foreach ($employees as $employee2) {
        echo '
        <div id="' . $employee2[0] . '" class="modal hide fade container" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ........
            </div>
        </div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Now you can do somethig like this so you don't need a reference to the id:

**jQuery**

```
$('.prev').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide').prev('.modal').modal('show');
});
$('.next').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide').next('.modal').modal('show');
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/fjYFm/)**

Comment: This works partially. The main problem with a live site is modals are removed from the dom on show, then reinserted below last element in group of modals when closed, so this had some weird behaviour. Essentially first time thru the next clicks everything works, then after closed the order is all mixed up not relating to the thumbnail order anymore.

Comment: here is my final code which works great. `$('.prev').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var modalId = $('.modal.in').attr('id');
  var link = $("a.modalLink[href='#" + modalId + "']");
  var prev = $(link);
  var previous = $(link.parent().prev().find('a.modalLink'));
  var previousId = $(previous).attr('href');
  $('.modal').modal('hide');
  $(previousId).modal('show');
 });`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript codes like

```
function showNext(){
    $('#current_id').modal('hide');
    $('#next_id').modal('show');
}
```

you can populate next_id like `next_id = current_id + 1`.

Comment: is there a way to do this without hardcoding the id